# Is it true that a tarball can change where files are extracted to regardless of the commands used to extract it?

Tags: filenames, tar

I have a coworker who says you need to be careful extracting tarballs because they can make changes you don't know about. I always thought a tarball was just a hierarchy of compressed files, so if you extract it to /tmp/example/ it can't possibly sneak a file into /etc/ or anything like that.

Comment: What Operating System environment(s) are you concerned with? GNU/Linux's tar has a `-P` option that influences its behavior in this regard.

Comment: I guess CentOS in this case, but I'd like to know whatever I should know.

Comment: For a longer time, GNU tar could be fooled in a way that allowed to make it e.g. remove `/etc/passwd` in case it was run as root. Since a while, I believe that `gtar` gives similar security as you get with `star`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Different tar utilities behave differently in this regard, so it's good to be careful. For a tar file that you didn't create, always list the table of contents before extracting it.

**[Solaris tar](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/tar-1.html):**

> The named files are extracted from the tarfile and written to the directory specified in the tarfile, relative to the current directory. Use the relative path names of files and directories to be extracted.
>
> Absolute path names contained in the tar archive are unpacked using the absolute path names, that is, the leading forward slash (/) is not stripped off.

In the case of a tar file with full (absolute) path names, such as:

```
/tmp/real-file
/etc/sneaky-file-here
```

... if you extract such a file, you'll end up with both files.

**[GNU tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/absolute.html):**

> By default, GNU tar drops a leading `/` on input or output, and complains about file names containing a `..` component. There is an option that turns off this behavior:
>
> `--absolute-names`
>
> `-P`
>
> Do not strip leading slashes from file names, and permit file names containing a `..` file name component.

... if you extract a fully-pathed tar file using GNU tar *without* using the `-P` option, it will tell you:

> tar: Removing leading `/` from member names

and will extract the file into subdirectories of your current directory.

**[AIX tar](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/tar.htm):**

says nothing about it, and behaves as the Solaris tar -- it will create and extract tar files with full/absolute path names.

**[HP-UX tar](https://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/B2355-60130/tar.1.html):**
<sup>(better online reference welcomed)</sup>

> **WARNINGS**
>
> There is no way to restore an absolute path name to a relative position.

**[OpenBSD tar](https://man.openbsd.org/tar):**

> `-P`
>
> Do not strip leading slashes (`/`) from pathnames.  The default is to strip leading slashes.

There are `-P` options implemented for `tar` on macOS, FreeBSD and NetBSD as well, with the same semantics, with the addition that `tar` on [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tar(1)) and macOS will "refuse to extract archive entries whose pathnames contain `..` or
         whose target directory would be altered by a symlink" without `-P`.

**[schilytools star](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html):**

> `-/`
>
> Don't  strip  leading  slashes  from  file  names  when extracting  an  archive.  Tar archives containing absolute pathnames are usually a bad idea. With  other  tar implementations,  they  may possibly never be extracted without clobbering existing files. Star for  that  reason,  by  default strips leading slashes from filenames when in extract mode.

Comment: For a long time, GNU tar ignored the fact that a path name containing `..` is a security risk, so use `star` or a recent `gtar`. Also have a look at the `star` example tar archives that include hand crafted `tar` headers that cause most `tar` implementations to remove files without even a warning.

Comment: @schily, according to Jeff's quotes, doesn't that apply to `tar` on Solaris, AIX and HP-UX, too? If so, why point out only GNU tar, especially if (again according to the quote above), they've changed to not accepting `..`? Issues with malformed input are of course bugs, and I suppose you've reported them as such.

Comment: Historic tar implementations are not checking things like that. I needed to make the remark because there was the claim that GNU tar is without problems without mentioning a release. And BTW: a list like this without mentioning `star` (the oldest free implementation) must be seen as incomplete.

Comment: @schily, I searched for man pages for major OS's (that may have different tar implementations); if you have a link to star's online man page, I'd be happy to include it.

Comment: Check http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html

Comment: BTW: `star` uses the option `-P` for a different use case since 1985, this is before gnu tar started to exist. Star uses `-/` since 1994 and I believe this is before gnu tar started to use `-P`.

Comment: @schily, maybe you should write your own answer if you have a better one.

Comment: Why? your answer is otherwise good...

Comment: ilkkachu != Jeff

Comment: @schily I take it you are the author of `star`?  Or do you just happen to have a matching name?  (No implication of impropriety by the way, just wanting to get clarity.)

Comment: @schily, did you get my email?

Comment: See also some list of past vulnerabilities in [GNU tar](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-72/product_id-1394/GNU-TAR.html) or [libarchive (bsdtar)](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-12872/Libarchive.html).

Comment: What about bypassing these restrictions by extracting a symlink to an absolute path or path containing `..`, then extracting further files under the symlink? Which tars defend against that?

Comment: I am the author of `star` since 1982.

Comment: @R.: A tar that prevents redirection via symlinks in general would be very slow and would prevent expected behavior. The general rule is that a tar implementation should be safe if you extract an archive inside an empty directory.

Comment: @schily: I'm talking about an attack in an empty directory. tar file first contains a symlink `evil_link->/` then a file `evil_link/etc/passwd`. Asking whether there are tar utilities that fail to prevent this sort of thing is a legitimate question.

Comment: @R..: Perhaps you can ask that as a standalone question.  I think it is very interesting.

Answer (score 9):

One of the hilarious things that happen with [tar bombs](http://www.linfo.org/tarbomb.html) is that they change the permissions of the current directory to the one included in the tarball.

For instance, if a tarball includes the '.' directory, and you unpack it in /tmp as root, it will wreck your system by making the /tmp unwritable by anybody but root.

Comment: And if you unpack it in `/`, it will change the permissions of the root directory, which will have unexpected consequences (I remember getting "cannot execute /bin/bash" when logging in on a console, because `/` was mode 770).

Comment: I've had this happen with official software - the github releases of "rancher-compose" all contain "." in the tar file, for example, and nuke /tmp if you extract them there.